# Recursive promises in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, promise, q

I want to traverse through a html5 file system and have some sort of notification once all files have been traversed.

Im using [filer](https://github.com/ebidel/filer.js) which is a wrapper for the html file system library

in order to start the recursive file system walker im using this:

```
filerService.ls(filerService.fs.root, function(entries){
  for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i ++) {
    traverseFileTree(entries[i]);
  }
});
```

the recursive function:

```
function traverseFileTree(item) {

    if(item.isFile) {
         console.log("item is file: " + item.name); 
         //do something with file here

    } else if (item.isDirectory) {
        console.log("item is directory: " + item.name); 

        filerService.ls(item, function(entries) {

            for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i ++) {
                traverseFileTree(entries[i]);
            }
        }); 
    }
};
```

Now I would like to do the following:

```
var promise = walkFileTree() //this method should start the recursive methods and return a promise

promise.then(function(){
  //notify user that the filewalker has completed
})
```

anyone have some pointers on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 3):

It can be accomplished using an array of promises (one for each subdirectory) and `$q.all()`. An untested outline of the solution would be:

```
function walkFileTree(item) {
    var d = $q.defer(), promises = [d.promise]; // we need at least one promise because we do not know beforehand the number of included directories
    if( typeof(item) === "undefined" ) item = filerService.fs.root;
    filerService.ls(item, function(entries){
        for(var i = 0; i < entries.length; i ++) {
            promises.push(traverseFileTree(entries[i]));
        }
        d.resolve();
    });
    return $q.all(promises);
}

function traverseFileTree(item) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    if(item.isFile) {
        console.log("item is file: " + item.name);
        //do something with file here
        d.resolve();
        return d.promise;
    }
    else if (item.isDirectory) {
        console.log("item is directory: " + item.name); 

        return walkFileTree(item);
    }
};
```

Note that `walkFileTree(item)` will iterate the item, while `walkFileTree()` will iterate the root.

*As I said this is untested and will probably need tweaking, but it demonstrates (I think) the outline for a solution.*

Comment: yes perfect, thanks this helps me put things into perspective.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work as intended. i cant seem to get the promises to be resolved once all the files have been traversed.

Comment: since there are some dependencies such as filer and the html 5 file system i cant seem to get the plunk/fiddle to play nice. i have been trying various things with the code u gave me. the problem is that $q.all(promises) gets fulfilled to early. this means that after going over 1-2 directories all promises seem to be fulfilled.